# Confused over something occuring with includes + echo

Tags: php, include, echo

My issue is as follows below, if anyone could help explain why the following is happening, and how to fix it; that would be amazing!

The long and short of my problem is that i have written some code (that completely works when within the main script!), but I need to place this code within multiple scripts. Therefore I have tried making this code into an 'include' file.

When the include file is executed, only the 'echo "TEST";' from the '$_GET['ffd'];' variable gets written to the HTML page. I'm highly confused about why it matters - as the other things should be written to the page regardless... the 'echo' statements below the { _ _ } of the '$_GET['ffd'];' are never written to the HTML page.

I know the files exist because when the script is ran within the main script (without the includes) it finds the files and correctly places the forms on the HTML page.

This is the includes in the main script I have been using. (when I move the code from the main script to the includes file)

```
include("includes/forcedlfile.inc");
```

The contents of the includes file are IDENTICAL to the contents of the PHP script shown at the bottom (i.e. copied and pasted) when ran within the main PHP script or the included .inc file.

Script being executed:

```
    //THE BIT THAT ALWAYS ECHO's TO THE HTML PAGE
if(isset($_GET['ffd']))
{
    echo "TEST";

            //OTHER THINGS NOT RELEVANT HERE
}

    //CODE THAT SHOULD BE EXECUTED REGARDLESS OF BEING WITHIN THE MAIN BODY OF THE SCRIPT OR WITHIN AN INCLUDES FILE
$homeworkid_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'homeworktasks' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $chosenhomework;
if (file_exists($homeworkid_dir))
{
    echo "<b>Download Homework Attachments: </b>";
    $attachmentno = 0;
    $contents = array_diff(scandir($homeworkid_dir, 1), array('..', '.', '.htaccess'));
    foreach($contents as $file)
    {
        $attachmentno = $attachmentno + 1;
        $file_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'homeworktasks' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $chosenhomework . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
        $btn = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file_dir);
        $btn = end($btn);
        $dllink = end($fsh);

    //ONLY WRITTEN TO PAGE WHEN WITHIN THE ORIGINAL SCRIPT, NOT 'INCLUDE' FILE
        echo "<form action='".$dllink."?tsk=".$homeworkid."&ffd=y' method='post'>
        Attachment ".$attachmentno.":
        <input type='hidden' name='dldir' value='".$file_dir."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='homeworkid' value='".$homeworkid."'>
        <input type='submit' value='Click Here To Download: ".$btn."'>
        </form>";
    }
}
```

If I place the file within the includes **and** the main script and submit the form (from the main script) I end up with two lots of 'TEST' appearing on the screen, and ONLY ONE form submission button - when **I should have two**.

Comment: I've editted the All-caps out of your post, but you can do that in the future too. Its a little hard determining whats in the 'include' file, and whats not. Can you edit your question so there are two code blocks, one for the "main script" and the other for the "included file"?

Comment: Thank you, I shall use the forum bold tags in future, however zpr has answered and fixed my issue so I won't waste any more of your time by making you look at something that has already been fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because `dirname(__FILE__)` is returning the directory of the current file, which is now in `./includes`, so it is unable to find the file.

You could use `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` to get the parent directory.